# How to install multiple python version on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I have already python `2.7.9` in `C:\Python27`

I try to install [python 2.7.6](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/python-2.7.6.msi) from python.org on `C:\Python276`

And after the installation :

- `C:\Python27\python.exe --version` return `Python 2.7.9`
- `C:\Python276\python.exe --version` return `Python 2.7.9`

Am I missing something ?

How to install multiple python version on Windows 7 (Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7601]) ?

Comment: python.exe is a loader that's linked to the interpreter DLL, e.g. python27.dll. The problem is likely you installed both versions for all users. Try installing 2.7.6 for just the current user. That should install the DLL to `C:\Python276`.

Comment: @eryksun can you add your answer, I can't accept a comment ! thank you for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@eryksun give the solution :

python.exe is a loader that's linked to the interpreter DLL, e.g. python27.dll. The problem is likely you installed both versions for all users.

Try installing 2.7.6 for just the current user. That should install the DLL to C:\Python276.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Python Launcher for Windows` which allows you to specify which version you want to execute using a shebang. Just place one of these at the top of your script to do so.

```
#!python276
#!python279
```

Comment: py.exe will find and start python.exe for the requested version, but that won't help here. Both versions of python27.dll can't be simultaneously installed for all users in `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

Comment: What do you mean? This is Python 2.7.9 and 3.4.2 we're talking about.

Comment: And even multiple versions of Python 2 would still work. And `python27.dll` isn't even located there anyway.

Comment: The OP is trying to have both 2.7.9 and 2.7.6 installed, but python.exe for 2.7.6 ends up using the python27.dll installed by 2.7.9. That means both must have been an all-user installation, which stores the DLL in `%SystemRoot%\System32`. Typically that's `C:\Windows\System32`.

Comment: I remove python 3.4 information from my post, it's confusing